# ValueError: too many values to unpack, can't figure out why

Tags: python

I have a function:

```
def store(word, info_list):
    for a, b, c, in info_list:
        data = {}
        ...
```

and I am calling:

```
store(x[0],x[1])
```

Where

```
x = (u'sergeev', (u'2015 afc asian cup group b', 
(u'2015 afc asian cup group b', u'sergeev', 372.57022256331544), 0.22388357256778307))
```

My goal is to make:

```
a=u'2015 afc asian cup group b'
b=(u'2015 afc asian cup group b', u'sergeev', 372.57022256331544)
c=0.22388357256778307
```

But I got

```
in store
for a,b,c, in info_list:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I couldn't find where the mismatch was...can anyone help me out?

Comment: Yepp the main reason being that if you assign X that way it won't be a list that you can iterate over the way you do because that will iterate over the 3 items one by one and not as a group. Try `x = (('2015... ', ' 2015... ',  0.22),)` and see the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `for` loop, simply *unpack* the elements.

```
def store(word, info_list):
    a, b, c = info_list
```

`x[1]` (the value you are passing to the function) is basically a *simple* tuple. Simply unpacking the values would suffice here.

You can use `for` loop when you have a tuple of tuples. Have a look at the example below:

```
>>> a = ((1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4))
>>> for i, j in a:
...     print i, j  
1 2
2 3
3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't that need to be looped, why not just assign it like this :

```
def store(word, info_list):
    a, b, c = info_list[0], info_list[1], info_list[2]
```